# Is there any way to programmatically check whether AppFabric cache host is active?

Tags: c#, .net, status, appfabric, host

I want to get `AppFabric` cache host's running status through c# programming. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `Powershell` commands following these steps;

- Download [`PowerShell v2 SDK`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2560)
- Create an environment for running our Powershell commands.

> ```
> var initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
> initialSessionState.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
> runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState);
> runspace.Open();
> ```

- Let's create a PipeLine.

> `var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();`

- Pass the command lines to pipeline in Powershell where run in cache.

> ```
> pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Use-CacheCluster"));
> pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Get-CacheHost"));
> ```

`Get-CacheHost` gives us cache server information. And run with `Invoke()` method.

> `var result = pipeline.Invoke();`

- With `result` object,

> ```
> var initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
> initialSessionState.ImportPSModule(new[] { "DistributedCacheAdministration" });
> initialSessionState.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
>
> runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState);
>
> runspace.Open();
>
> var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
> pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Use-CacheCluster"));
> pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Get-CacheHost"));
> var result = pipeline.Invoke();
>
> var hostInfo = (HostInfo)result[0].BaseObject;
>
> Console.Out.WriteLine("Server Name        : " + hostInfo.HostName);
> Console.Out.WriteLine("Server Port      : " + hostInfo.PortNo);
> Console.Out.WriteLine("Server Service Name : " + hostInfo.ServiceName);
> Console.Out.WriteLine("Server Status    : " + hostInfo.Status);
> Console.Out.WriteLine("Server Version     : " + hostInfo.VersionInfo);
> ```

Also, don't forget to add these assembly references;

- `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client`
- `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core`
- `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Management`
- `System.Management.Automation`

Comment: I'm aware of Powershell commands. Are there any AppFabric API's through which we can achieve this?

Comment: Actually, I don't know any appfabric api for doing this.